# "Reply him" or "reply to him"

Tags: transitivity

I always say sentences like "**Reply him** that you will deliver the report later". A friend of mine who is rather particular about English grammar says it should be "**Reply to him** that [...]". Is this variation correct? Is my usage wrong, or just as acceptable?

I feel that it's unnecessary to have that **'to'** there and only serves to break the *natural flow* of speaking without adding anything extra, if you know what I mean. Besides, you do not say "Tell to him" but you say "Tell him". But interestingly you say "Speak to him" or "Talk to him".

Similarly:

- **Reply her** *or* **Reply to her**
- **Reply his email** *or* **Reply to his email**

PS: I can't find any answer to this by searching on Google or this site.

Comment: It's an interesting question, in that I'd say _answer her_, but _reply **to** her_. At least you know what those notations of [_<tr>_ & _<intr>_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/answer) mean now.

Comment: "Reply him" or "Reply her" are dead giveaways to my ear that the speaker / writer is non-native. (in case that idiom is not familiar, "dead giveaway" means "something that reveals a fact or an intention completely." but I don't know its origin)

Comment: What about "give him" vs. "give to him"?

Comment: I suppose the usage of [give](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give) depends on context, since it can be transitive (for some meanings of the verb) or intransitive (for other meanings).

Answer (score 12):

Your friend is correct.  "Reply" is typically an *intransitive verb*, which means it does not take a direct object.   "Tell", by contrast, is a *transitive verb*, which does take a direct object.  So:

> Please reply him.   (**Incorrect**)
>
> Please reply to him. (**Correct**)
>
> Please tell him.   (**Correct**)

It doesn't matter whether the subject is a person you're replying to or an email you're replying about - the rule is the same.

> Please reply his email. (**Incorrect**)
>
> Please reply to his email. (**Correct**)

[M-W Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reply) shows that you can also use "reply" as a transitive verb, but that's a more specialized use such as you would see in dialogue:

> "I'd like some water please," she replied.

Comment: Oh my. The technical term for this is [intransitive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb). A phrasal verb is something else entirely, like "give up" or "sign in". −1 for that.

Comment: What if the object is the person to whom the reply should be sent to? Would that be _'Please reply to him'_ and **not** _'Please reply him'_?

Comment: @ЯegDwight A simple mistake, and you rated -1 for the whole answer. Now he or she isn't on SE anymore to reply _to_ my comment. I think Lynn tried their best, and I think that deserves some appreciation. [PS: Where did the other -1 come from?]

Comment: @ЯegDwight - Ooops, you're right - I'm a dummy.  Serves me right for blindly copying/pasting from an ESL site that listed "talk to" as a phrasal verb.

Comment: @ADTC - I'm still here, my account just wasn't linked to this site yet.  I answered your comment and fixed the original mistake in the revised answer.

Comment: @ Lynn: I'm afraid all those (now-obsolete) downvotes made me a bit careless when I skimmed you (now perfectly valid) answer. No matter - since I've gone to the trouble of flagging up some actual usage figure, I'll leave my answer there. But +1 to yours for the terminology (now it's actually *correct!* :)

Comment: @Lynn your answer clearly shows the logic. It is due to the verbs being **transitive** or **intransitive** that _reply him_ is incorrect, while _tell him_ or _answer him_ are correct. My next question is, why isn't _reply_ a transitive verb (other than the exception you pointed out)?

Comment: [This page](http://www.writingcentre.uottawa.ca/hypergrammar/trnsintr.html) mentions that many verbs can be transitive or intransitive depending on the usage. So, it's not really an either-or conundrum, because verbs can be both. Besides, language is flexible **and** arbitrary. Grammar rules are only built to avoid confusion. And saying _native speakers don't speak that way and therefore it's wrong_ is a bit weird when you think about it - most users of English are 'immigrant' speakers. But I would be leaving language and getting into philosophy if I go that way.

Comment: @ADTC - Yeah, I can understand the confusion.  Perhaps a linguist could explain why reply is usually intransitive but tell is usually transitive.  I can only offer an unsatisfying "because that's how it is".  I can hit something, break something, fix something, tell something, or drive something, but I can't reply something (other than that exception about a quote).  The "rules" have evolved, influenced by stuff in other languages, and don't always make logical sense.

Answer (score 5):

Native speakers never omit the preposition between *reply* and *[recipient]*. From Google Books...

> [[We haven't] replied **to** him yet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22replied%20to%20us%20yet%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22replied%20to%20him%20yet%22&oq=%22replied%20to%20him%20yet%22&gs_l=serp.3...6518.7598.0.8254.5.5.0.0.0.0.67.285.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.WhFW96tylPk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47810305,d.d2k&fp=35cb3c9b55bc8b43&biw=1296&bih=930) (868 hits)
>   [[We haven't] replied him yet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22replied%20him%20yet%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (2 hits - but actually they're probably duplicates anyway)

Looking more closely at the second instance(s), I think there's strong evidence to suggest the writer isn't even a native speaker of English anyway.

---

In such contexts, *reply* (as with similar words such as *respond, react*) normally requires the preposition ***to*** if a recipient is explicitly specified - unlike, say, *answer* or *tell*, which don't normally have a preposition between verb and [patient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_%28grammar%29) (*patient = **object** of an action = the person replied **to***).

Another common "object" of the verb *reply* is *the **noun** "reply" (the text of the reply itself*). That's to say...

> *"This is the answer" replied John.*
>    which could be resequenced as
>    *John replied "This is the answer".*

is what's called "transitive" usage. The conventional definition of a [transitive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb) is *a verb that requires one or more objects*, but I'm not sure that's particularly helpful here. It makes more sense to me to say...

> The verb ***reply*** can either be used intransitively (i.e. - with no "object"), or with one or both of two types of object - the response itself (no preposition) and/or the person addressed (preceded by ***to***).

Comment: I never said I'm a native speaker of English. You could have been less condescending in your answer... Drop the emotions and it would be a good answer.

Comment: Btw, thanks. I never ever heard of a grammatical _patient_ :) I have only learnt it as _verb and object_, not _verb and patient_. That's nice to know.

Comment: @ADTC: I assumed you *weren't* a native speaker, actually, otherwise I didn't see how you'd be unaware a standard usage which is more strictly observed than many. But I didn't mean to be condescending to you personally, just the usage. Whatever - I'll edit the first sentence in a minute. I don't know when linguists started using *patient* (I don't recall it from my college days in the 70s), but it certainly seems very useful to me. I included a definition in because I suppose many people here won't know the usage, but it deserves to be promoted.

Comment: Thanks :) I did a little reading from the link you provided; _patient_ is not exactly the same as _object_. In a passive sentence, the patient would be the subject, because that is what the action (_verb_) is carried upon. So I guess that distinction is why linguists introduced this definition.

Comment: @ADTC: Yes, *subject* and *object* are very crude categories. At least identifying *subject* tells you what ***verb** form* you need, but *object* doesn't help for much. Saying a verb is "ditransitive" because it can take two objects (almost arbitrarily distinguished as *direct* and *indirect*) seems equally trite. Many verbs can take multiple "objects" if they're allowed to be attached to prepositions. [But would you call "dig" a ditransive verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/2637) just because it can take two objects without needing a preposition?